# CSS color values are highlighted

Tags: css, colors

How can I disable the color-value highlight in Visual Studio?:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Code Open the Preferences by either

- using `CTRL+SHIFT+P` (or on Mac `CMD+SHIFT+P`) and Type `Preferences` and hitting `Enter`
- or in the Menu `Code > Preferences > Settings`

Once inside the Settings View, search for `Color Decorators` and disable the checkbox.